# why does the overlaying content in the admin mode not show up anymore?

Tags: javascript, theming, modal-dialogs

Okay, my Drupal admin interface used to work just fine until I introduced some `jQuery` and `CSS` changes this morning for the mobile adaptive interface. Now, When I'm in admin mode and for example click on the drop down to `Configure block` on my page, the page grays out but the white overlay interface to change the contents never shows up. I tried with `Chrome`, `Chromium` & `Firefox` which all yield the same result. The URL of my site is http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/ and if you resize the width `<900px` you'll see the little nav button poppintg up on to left - that's what I have changed... what did I mess up?

Comment: Users should not need to see your site to answer the question, which also means they should not need to look at the source of the page to see which JavaScript is used, and which CSS styles are used to tell you what is wrong. Take off the site URL, and the question gets too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there is a JavaScript error in your nmost recent changes which is stalling some other scripts.

To get your admin interface back temporarily disable the Overlay module (core). 
http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/admin/modules

Then use the browsers developer console to find out where the JavaScript error is. If you've used the jQuery Update module you might need to set a different version of jquery for the Admin pages which is in the config page too. 
http://quaaoutlodge.com/admin/config/development/performance

Comment: Hi, Thanks, disabling the overaly module fixed things for me actually, I don't see any advantage in the overlay module anyways...  I don't know what the "jQuery Update module" is nor have I used it. I don't see how I can set a different jQuery version on the link you pasted. But it might very well be that i've ran in some kind of version conflict... Thanks for your help!

Comment: jQuery Update updates Drupal's version of jQuery to a newer version. Unfortunately this sometimes causes a conflict on admin pages that are expecting older versions. So jQuery Update provides a mechanism for using different versions on the backend. https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update